# Is it correct to say: please refer to my resume?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

In my cover letters, I give a summary of my resume. Then, I want to say that if you need more info about my resume, please refer to my resume.

I feel that this is not the correct usage. If that is the case, then are there any other words I can use instead?

And how about introducing a paraphrasing tag?

Comment: This question isn't really about English language and usage, so it's not on-topic here. You might find some helpful resume/cover letter tips on [workplace.SE] though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds fine to me, although I'd probably just say "please see my resume."

What sounds awkward in your example sentence is the repetition of "resume."  I'd avoid that by saying e.g.

> "For more information about my studies and work experience, please see the attached résumé."

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following up the summary with a phrase like "Additional details on my experience/work with these areas are included in my attached resume."